# What is ForkJoinPool Async mode

Tags: java, threadpool, fork-join, forkjoinpool

What does Async mode of ForkJoinPool mean? Javadoc mentions that it makes queues (is it per-thread queue?) FIFO instead of LIFO. What does it mean in practice?

Answer (score 23):

Each worker thread in a `ForkJoinPool` has its own work queue. ***[Async mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-boolean-)*  concerns the order in which each worker takes forked tasks that are never joined from its work queue.**

Workers in a `ForkJoinPool` in async mode process such tasks in FIFO (first in, first out) order. By default, `ForkJoinPool`s process such tasks in LIFO (last in, first out) order.

It's important to emphasise that the async mode setting only concerns *forked tasks that are never joined.* When using a `ForkJoinPool` for what it was originally designed for, namely recursive fork/join task decomposition, `asyncMode` doesn't come into play at all. Only when a worker is not engaged in actual fork/join processing does it execute async tasks, and only then is the `asyncMode` flag actually queried.

Here's a small program that demonstrates the difference between the two different async mode settings:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Demo of {@code ForkJoinPool} behaviour in async and non-async mode.
 */
public class ForkJoinAsyncMode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set the asyncMode argument below to true or false as desired:
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(
                4, ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, true);

        pool.invoke(new RecursiveRangeAction(0, 200));
        pool.awaitQuiescence(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * A {@code ForkJoinTask} that prints a range if the range is smaller than a
     * certain threshold; otherwise halves the range and proceeds recursively.
     * Every recursive invocation also forks off a task that is never joined.
     */
    private static class RecursiveRangeAction extends RecursiveAction {
        private static final AtomicInteger ASYNC_TASK_ID = new AtomicInteger();

        private final int start;
        private final int end;

        RecursiveRangeAction(int start, int end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            if (end - start < 10) {
                System.out.format("%s range [%d-%d] done%n",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), start, end);
            } else {
                int mid = (start + end) >>> 1;
                int id = ASYNC_TASK_ID.incrementAndGet();

                System.out.format(
                        "%1$s [%2$d-%3$d] -< [%3$d-%4$d], fork async task %5$d%n",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), start, mid, end, id);

                // Fork off additional asynchronous task that is never joined.
                ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> {
                    System.out.format("%s async task %d done%n",
                            Thread.currentThread().getName(), id);
                }).fork();

                invokeAll(new RecursiveRangeAction(start, mid),
                        new RecursiveRangeAction(mid, end));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In **non-async mode** (the default for `ForkJoinPool`), forked tasks that are never joined are executed in LIFO order.

When you run the example program in non-async mode, looking at the output of one worker you might see a pattern like the following:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 [175-187] -< [187-200], fork async task 10
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 [175-181] -< [181-187], fork async task 11
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 range [175-181] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 range [181-187] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 [187-193] -< [193-200], fork async task 12
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 range [187-193] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 range [193-200] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 async task 12 done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 async task 11 done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 async task 10 done
```

Here, tasks 10, 11, 12 are forked and later executed in reverse order once the worker gets around to executing them.

In **async mode** on the other hand, again looking at the output of one worker the pattern would rather look like the following:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 [150-175] -< [175-200], fork async task 8
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 [150-162] -< [162-175], fork async task 9
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 [150-156] -< [156-162], fork async task 10
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 range [150-156] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 range [156-162] done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 [162-168] -< [168-175], fork async task 11
...
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 async task 8 done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 async task 9 done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 async task 10 done
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 async task 11 done
```

Tasks 8, 9, 10, 11 are forked and later executed in the order they were submitted.

When to use which mode? Whenever a `ForkJoinPool` thread pool is chosen to take advantage of its work-stealing properties rather than for recursive fork/join task processing, async mode is probably the more natural choice, as tasks get executed in the order they are submitted.

Async event-driven frameworks like [`CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) are sometimes said to profit from async mode. For example, when constructing a complex chain of `CompletableFuture` callbacks, then a custom `ForkJoinPool` executor in async mode might perform slightly better than the default executor. (I can't speak from experience though.)

Comment: What's the purpose though? Latency? Making it more CPU-friendly somehow?

Comment: In order to utilize the asyncMode, I would recommend using `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()`. Your custom ForkJoinPool implementation is same as the work-stealing ExecutorService, with just a change in the parallelism count. My General Rule of Thumb for LIFO: ForkJoinPool's commonPool, for FIFO: work-stealing ExecutorService.

Answer (score 7):

It is meant for event-style tasks that are submitted but never joined.
So basically tasks that are getting executed for their side-effects, not for returning a result that will be processed by the forking task after joining.